# Obj-C/Cocoa: Use of Shortcut Recorder Framework, how?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, shortcut, recorder, mac-frameworks

to capture keystrokes for registering global hotkeys i want to use the shortcut recorder. but i can't get it to work. here is what i have done so far:

- checked out the current version from the svn
- installed xcode 3 because my xcode 4 wouldn't build, then built it with xcode 3
- in xcode 4, i added the shortcutrecorder.framework in the build-directory to my application, dragged/copied the SRRecorderControl.h to my application directory and inserted

`#import "SRRecorderControl.h"`

to my AppDelegate.h

when i build and run, it fails and says images not found. i know that there are images in the shortcut recorder main directory, but i dont know where to put these. and: how do i add the special shortcut recorder textfield to my main window?

Comment: I'm working on the same thing.  I found someone who had created an Xcode4-friendly fork:  https://github.com/Kentzo/ShortcutRecorder

Answer (score 1):

You forgot 'Copy Frameworks' stage. Add ShortcutRecorder.framework to 'Copy Frameworks'.

You can find it on build phase of target information.